# opencv on ubuntu namespace cv error

Tags: c++, opencv

Hi wen i build my code i get error message that is

./src/view.o: In function `cv::Mat::MSize::MSize(int*)':
/home/burak/desktop/workspace/deneme/Debug/../src/view.cpp:13: multiple definition of`main'
./src/deneme.o:/home/burak/desktop/workspace/deneme/Debug/../src/deneme.cpp:12: first         defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [deneme] Error 1

My code is

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp> 
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<cv.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
if( argc != 2)
{
 cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
 return -1;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
{
    cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}
///// Show Image... and main return 0 ///
```

how can i solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two `main()` functions (one in `view.cpp` on line 13 and one in `deneme.cpp` on line 12). You can only have one `main()` function outside namespaces (i.e. as your entry point).

Comment: thank i solved above problem but now libopencv_core.so.2.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
But my library is there. ?

Comment: make sure you link to the correct file, depending on your system you might have to (or should) link to `libopencv_core.so` rather than naming a specific version. If that still doesn't work, try to find it with `locate` or create a separate questions.